# running node.js http server on multiple ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Please can anybody help me to find out how to get the server socket context in node.js, so that i will come to know request came on which port number on my server.
I can read the server port if i request using http headers but I want it through network and something like socket context which tells request came on which port number.

Here is the sample code:

```
var http=require('http');
var url = require('url');
var ports = [7006, 7007, 7008, 7009];
var servers = [];
var s;
function reqHandler(req, res) {
        var serPort=req.headers.host.split(":");
        console.log("PORT:"+serPort[1]);//here i get it using http header.
}
ports.forEach(function(port) {
    s = http.createServer(reqHandler);
    s.listen(port);
    servers.push(s);
});
```

Comment: Each HTTP server can only listen to one port at a time.  Also, this is super easy to do with Express.  http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen

Comment: What do you mean by network/socket context ? without getting request on the server.

Comment: socket context means whole connection object on the particular listen socket.I just wanted to know on which of the above ports request came on the sever.

Comment: @Brad So uh... how to listen on two ports at once then with identical behavior on both?

Answer (score 11):

The `req` object has a reference to the underlying node socket.  You can easily get this information as documented at: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_socket and http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_remoteaddress

Here is your sample code modified to show the local and remote socket address information.

```
var http=require('http');
var ports = [7006, 7007, 7008, 7009];
var servers = [];
var s;
function reqHandler(req, res) {
    console.log({
        remoteAddress: req.socket.remoteAddress,
        remotePort: req.socket.remotePort,
        localAddress: req.socket.localAddress,
        localPort: req.socket.localPort,
    });
}
ports.forEach(function(port) {
    s = http.createServer(reqHandler);
    s.listen(port);
    servers.push(s);
});
```