# How to structure a React App with several functional areas on different ports?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

A web application that we are building must have 3 different "areas" accessible on 3 different ports, for example:

- localhost:9001 - for Admins
- localhost:9002 - for Customers
- localhost:9003 - for Non-Registered users

The back-end is built on Hapi/Node and exposes many API endpoints to be consumed by the UI. The front-end must now be built in React - the three areas should share common UI elements, but being on different ports each of them may have unique UI features.

How would you go about structuring the front-end code (React) of the application in this scenario?

Until now, I would use **create-react-app** and build an app that in practice has only 1 port - and use authentication/authorization to limit certain functionalities. Now, with three different functional areas, should there be 3 separate create-react-apps, one for each area, living in the same root project? Would the shared UI elements be inside a separate "Shared" module and then the 3 different apps would import the components from there?

All advice on how to structure a React App to work with (at least) 3 different ports / areas is much appreciated.

Comment: How does the UI differ for each one?

Comment: For the most part - buttons, layout, grid table, colors - the UI is absolutely the same. The only difference at this point would be certain unique functionalities and related unique components - for example, the Admin Area would have a "dashboard" screen with widgets unique to it. Same for the other areas.

Comment: Is there a reason to run each of these on different ports? It seems like it would be easier to design a permissions scheme and have the app render different UI components and make different functionality available depending on the permissions granted to the current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reference to have your application structure in a way to listen:

- localhost:9001 - for Admins
- localhost:9002 - for Customers
- localhost:9003 - for Non-Registered users

Is possible to implement, and `Node.js`, `react.js` totally support such structuring.
But I would first write my possible concerns as **pre-note** and then will advise **solution** to the question:

**Pre-Note:**

The case mentioned in the question is probably not ideal for every one, but only for some special cases (when you know WHY & WHAT you want to do).

In production environment you will only listen on port `80` (for *HTTP*) or `443` (for *HTTPS*) for *Visitors, Members, and for Admin*. Rest of the things will be handled by your application on its own.

In backend you can loadbalance traffice to number of machines (IPs), each running same application bundle & version. So, there seems no reason of using multiple ports against one URL. 
*(Let's conclude it here, otherwise it will go way broad and broad.)*

**Solution to the Question:**

Now if you want to structure your application as on 3 different ports (each for separate role or user type), which might assist you to setup additional access permissions for each `port`; then you will need your `Node.js` `server.js` file listen on multiple ports. Which is also possible as mentioned here: [running node.js http server on multiple ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296797/running-node-js-http-server-on-multiple-ports)

Or you can have different `server1.js`, `server2.js`, `server3.js` each listening on different port. You will then throw or render relevant `react.js` application `bundle` files. You will need to develop separate `react.js` application for each section (3 in total). This way you can scale and manage each section quite easily without mixing too much complexity from each section (web, member, admin).

Ofcourse, you will have one `node_modules/` which will be used by your `NodeJs` application. And you can run all 3 server files from one `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on running each piece on a different port, one solution is to build 3 separate apps for them to run on different ports. If there are any similarities in functionality for each interface, you should **not** duplicate the code. Instead, configure the builds in the `package.json` file so that you can more easily reuse use components and other code that each app shares in common.

Alternatively, you could design a permission scheme that determines what UI components and menu items are available depending on the permissions granted to the current user. For example, all components could have an `isAdmin` prop. When this prop is set to `true`, the prop renders components which are only available for adminstrators. Otherwise it renders normally. Overall, I believe this would be easier to implement and maintain than three separate apps.

Comment: any reference or little more detail with example will be good to understand. With theory its not very understandable.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan I have edited my question a couple of times. Is the most recent version closer to what you are suggesting?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan The decision to have 3 different "areas" running on 3 different ports is a requirement by the client. Among other concerns, they want to treat different ports differently - for example, the Admin port is supposed to be accessible only at certain offices and/or specific network; the Customer port is to be accessed by WiFi, but not Mobile Network; etc.

While I agree it is not impossible to achieve desired outcome with one port only, in the end of the day it was client's requirement.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan it sounds like you have a better idea of the necessary details here than I. You should write up your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that the response might be too late for the question at this point in time.

But, if you really want to explore more on your question. You can check out [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) tool.