# how can nodejs run single tcp server instance on multiple different ports on single nodejs process

Tags: node.js, listen

[image]

i want to listen multiple different tcp ports on single tcp server(i do not want to create multiple tcp servers).

I searched and found something similar here(for Java and .Net)
[Java Server - Multiple ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079172/java-server-multiple-ports)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/09828be4-6ac4-45ec-a116-508314dab793/listen-on-multiple-ports?forum=csharpgeneral

how can i do that in nodejs?

thank you.

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296797/running-node-js-http-server-on-multiple-ports

Comment: @shakirullah that sets up multiple tcp/http servers

Comment: @Free.Wong Can you explain your use case? node net servers only listen on a single port but you may be able to handle sockets like shakirullah suggested

Comment: What is the point of having different clients connect on different ports to the same server?  The whole point of a server is that it can allow multiple clients to connect to a single server on a single port.